# basic c++ memory allocation and strlen

Tags: c++

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

 char* myArr = new char[5];

 cout << strlen(myArr) << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

why does it print out 12 (instead of 5)?

**edit**: Adding myArr[**5**] = '\0'; fixes the problem. But it takes memory that isn't mine. Is that ok?

Comment: Try running the same program many times. Sometimes it may print some other value; it could be 0, 4, 7, 16, 19 etc..

Comment: When you allocated `char[5]`, your application "owns" 5 bytes, so setting `myArr[3]` (the 4th byte) to zero is perfectly valid, although the first 3 bytes are still not initialized.

Comment: Doing myArr[5] is writing past the end of the array. You are screwing up another data structure (which may or may not lead to a crash). PS. Have you looked at std::string. It does all the memory management for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The memory is uninitialized.  It has "random" data on the heap, so there just happens to be 12 non-zero bytes in it before the first zero (and it is reading past the allocated length).

Allocated memory does not contain (from the application's standpoint) length information.  If you put a 0 in the first byte, then the length would report as zero:

```
myArr[0] = 0;
```

If you declare it as follows (with the memory on the stack), the sizeof operator will give the "expected" value of 5.  And as delnan points out (thanks), it is important to note that sizeof is not returning the length of the array but rather the number of bytes.

```
char myArr[5];
cout << sizeof( myArr ) << endl;
```

Comment: The second trick won't work for arrays of T when `sizeof(T) != 1`. Use `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`.

Comment: That's a good point.  I will clarify that the sizeof operator returns the number of bytes (not the number of elements).

Answer (score 2):

> why does it print out 12 (instead of 5)?

Because you invoked undefined behavior , you called strlen() on uninitialized data, so anything could happen.

strlen() expects a c string, that is a sequence of char's that end with a 0 byte.

your `new char[5];` just returns memory that's not initialized and not suitable to pass to strlen() until you place a string in there.

Answer (score 1):

strlen searches for the first null character to determine the length. Since this memory has only been allocated, and not initialized, the first null character could be anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` returns the length of a null-terminated string. `new char[5]` returns a pointer to a memory block *big enough* to store a null-terminated string 5 `char`s long (4 characters + null terminator). However you did not actually put a string there!

Comment: 4 characters long. You need to use the 5 location for the null terminator.